# Jsonobject and Jsonarray management In Iteration

Tags: java, json, web-services

I am trying to send the details of Usrs and its items with json. But at time of json genertion, with iterated jsonarry with json object, i stuck t middle.how to manage Jsonrray and JsonObject for below given Iterated data.

```
{
"Data":
     {
       ["user":1],
        "items":
              [{"item":1},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4}]
     },
     {
       ["user":2],
        "items":
              [{"item":11},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4}]
     },
    {
       ["user":3],
        "items":
              [{"item":11},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4}]
     },
}
```

1. I am not sure, whether above given structure is perfect or not?
2. if perfect then how can I retrieve particular users 4th item?

Comment: Are you using one of the JSON libraries to create and parse your JSON? If not, I would suggest you do so. I use Google GSON and it's petty good. There's an online validator at [http://www.jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com) you can use. I've also used Stringtree to check my JSON in the past: [http://stringtree.org/stringtree-json.html](http://stringtree.org/stringtree-json.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel bad while writing (non-challenging) code for you, but I had my IDE open, and waiting for coffee. So, code for you.

```
    String s = "{\"Data\":[{\"user\":1,\"items\":[{\"item\":1},{\"item\":2},{\"item\":3},{\"item\":4}]},{\"user\":2,\"items\":[{\"item\":11},{\"item\":2},{\"item\":3},{\"item\":4}]},{\"user\":3,\"items\":[{\"item\":11},{\"item\":2},{\"item\":3},{\"item\":4}]}]}";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("Data");
    for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++){
        JSONObject userData = data.getJSONObject(i);
        if(userData.getInt("user") ==2 ){
              JSONArray items = userData.getJSONArray("items");
              JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(3);
              System.out.println("item#4: " + item.getInt("item"));
        }
    }
```

The correct JSON for you is

```
{
        "Data":[
             {
                "user":1,
                "items":
                      [{"item":1},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4}]
             },
             {
                "user":2,
                "items":
                      [{"item":11},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4}]
             },
            {
               "user":3,
                "items":
                      [{"item":11},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4}]
             }
             ]
}
```